# Making grub boot the CD-ROM

Tags: grub

Instead of going to the BIOS every time, I'd like to add an entry in grub menu to boot the CD-ROM.

Best definitive way of doing this ?

Comment: most folk just leave `CDROM` as the first boot device in the BIOS and the boot drive as second.  the BIOS will skip over the CD drive if it's empty.  any particular reason you've been changing the BIOS each time?

Comment: I do that too. But why grub wouldn't be able to do it ? It can boot from the network, does chaining... why not the CD-ROM ?

Comment: One reason to not let the BIOS do this is because it can sometimes drastically make the boot process slower (at least by about 1-5 seconds if there is something inside the drive).

Comment: @Gzorg, please accept the answer if it has helped you. This helps other users as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Download the memdisk.bin from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20050428162914/http://www.lrz-muenchen.de:80/~bernhard/memdisk.bin) or if you have syslinux installation, you can use the installed memdisk.bin.

Step 2: Download the sbootmgr.dsk from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060925171941/http://www.lrz-muenchen.de/~bernhard/sbootmgr.dsk) or if you have any version of Slackware CD-1, /isolinux/sbootmgr/sbootmgr.dsk file you can use.

Step 3: Copy both memdisk.bin and sbootmgr.dsk in your grub existing grub installation path, /boot/grub.

Step 4: Add the following entry in your existing grub menu. Note: root(hd0,0) should be according to your configuration.

```
title CDROM

root(hd0,0)

kernel /boot/grub/memdisk.bin

initrd /boot/grub/sbootmgr.dsk
```

Step 5: I hope you need not to run grub-install again. If necessary you can do.

Step 6: Reboot the machine.

Step 7: You can see an entry called CDROM in grub menu list. Select the entry. You will be shown boot device selection screen showing all your harddisk and CDROM drives. Insert your bootable CDROM in the CD Drive and select that drive from menu. Waavv..!! your machine is booted from that CD.

[Source](http://cutecomputer.wordpress.com/2006/10/10/boot-cdrom-through-grub/)

Comment: I saw this too, but I didn't know whether I should trust a third party thing like this. Given the disclaimer and the warnings one can find here http://www.lrz-muenchen.de/~bernhard/grub-chain-cd.html...

So I tried, and ... it hangs at "Loading boot sector... booting..."

Comment: Is this information from https://cutecomputer.wordpress.com/2006/10/10/boot-cdrom-through-grub/? It seems so, because your posts dates three years later.

Comment: Links broken, doesn't work anymore. It looks to be possible with a [slackware cd](http://www.slackware.com/getslack/torrents.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
title Boot from CD
cdrom --init
map --hook
chainloader (cd0)
boot
```

(I added boot command at the and line)

Comment: Does not work ...